# Why Docker NAT iptables has RETURN in first row?

Tags: docker, networking, iptables, nat

Hello StackOverflow users.

Now I'm studying docker nat network especially in iptables.

I executed docker command like below.
Make it to accessible from remote server computer.

```
docker run -d -p 32170:80 --name nginx_server nginx
```

When I investigate iptables nat table. I found something weird.

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere            !localhost/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.17.0.0/16        anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  192.168.123.0/24     base-address.mcast.net/24 
RETURN     all  --  192.168.123.0/24     255.255.255.255     
MASQUERADE  tcp  --  192.168.123.0/24    !192.168.123.0/24     masq ports: 1024-65535
MASQUERADE  udp  --  192.168.123.0/24    !192.168.123.0/24     masq ports: 1024-65535
MASQUERADE  all  --  192.168.123.0/24    !192.168.123.0/24    
MASQUERADE  tcp  --  172.17.0.2           172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:5000
MASQUERADE  tcp  --  172.17.0.3           172.17.0.3           tcp dpt:http

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:5000 to:172.17.0.2:5000
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:32170 to:172.17.0.3:80
```

As I searched, packet first checked in `PREROUTING`.
So its rule is like below and packet should go to `DOCKER` chain.

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
```

After it came to `DOCKER` chain.
My queistion is here... As like below all packets are matched to `RETURN` and back to previous chain.
If it is right, then when does its source address is changed to docker container and when does its port is changed to docker port?

```
Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

To summarize I have two questions

1. What is `ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL` meaning?
2. When and where does outside packet's source and port will be changed in iptables?
3. Is there any reference about iptables NAT in docker?

Comment: The first return is for packets coming from `docker0`. Use `iptables -nvL -t nat`.

Comment: @BMitch Oh thx a lot... It was a simple one haha :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try use `iptables -t nat -L -v`.
The result contins **in**.

```
Chain DOCKER (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 3088  185K RETURN     all  --  docker0 any     anywhere             anywhere
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  br-5db28a02ac5c any     anywhere             anywhere
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  !docker0 any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:postgres to:172.17.0.2:5432
   28  1792 DNAT       tcp  --  !docker0 any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:8084 to:172.17.0.3:8082
   14   860 DNAT       tcp  --  !docker0 any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:us-srv to:172.17.0.3:8081
```

Only package from docker0 will return